# Retrieving input from a .txt file

Tags: python, tkinter

Using the bellow .txt file, how is it possible to create a tkinter GUI that will take the txt file and create a new frame for each line of code. Is it possible to make separate buttons for them for them on each page?

```
#Hello.txt
 hi 
 hello
 here
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: What problems are you having? Do you know how to read a file? Do you know how to analyze whether a line has data in quotes? Do you know how to create frames? What part of this problem do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you want to have some code example of what it is you are trying to do and where you are stuck to ask a question here.

However this was not hard to visualize and I felt like building an example.

Here I have created a GUI that has 2 buttons and one label. I simply update the label at the next or previous index by using a tracking variable. If I reach the beginning of the list or end of the list the buttons will not do anything except print to console that you have reached the end.

This example should serve as a good foundation for what you are trying to do.

I have my `main.py` python file and my `data.txt` file in the same directory.

The `data.txt` file looks like this:

```
Row one in file.
Row two in file.
Row three in file.
```

The code is:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_of_data_in_file = []
        self.ndex = 0
        with open("data.txt", "r") as data:
            # Readlines() will convert the file to a list per line in file.
            self.list_of_data_in_file = data.readlines()
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text=self.list_of_data_in_file[self.ndex])
        self.lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

        tk.Button(self, text="Previous", command=self.previous).grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(self, text="Next", command=self.next).grid(row=0, column=2)

    def previous(self):
        # simple if statement to make sure we don't get errors when changing index on the list.
        if self.ndex != 0:
            self.ndex -= 1
            self.lbl.config(text=self.list_of_data_in_file[self.ndex])
        else:
            print("No previous index")

    def next(self):
        # simple if statement to make sure we don't get errors when changing index on the list.
        if self.ndex != (len(self.list_of_data_in_file) - 1):
            self.ndex += 1
            self.lbl.config(text=self.list_of_data_in_file[self.ndex])
        else:
            print("Reached end of list!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```